# Can we say "huge evolution"?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

Is this sentence true?

> The huge evolution of new technologies.

Comment: It’s not a complete sentence, just a phrase. The problem is that huge refers to size, e.g., a huge elephant. Instead, you need an adjective like dramatic or remarkable or even extensive.

Comment: I suggest "The evolutionary **leap** made by new technologies."

Answer (score 1):

> Evolution = a gradual process of change and development:
>
> [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/evolution)

So what, if anything, is a huge and gradual process? We might reasonably think of the huge and gradual process of landscape change during tectonic movements on large scales over geological times. In parallel we may think of the huge evolution of technologies on global or long times (steam, electricity, radio, digital being obvious examples).

Nevertheless, the suspicion remains that *huge evolution of new technologies* is sometimes a rearrangement of *evolution of huge new technologies*.

Or it may be that *huge* is being used as a qualifier of the gradualness (the *rate*) of the process of evolution, implying *rapid evolution of new technologies*.

Answer (score 0):

A search of [Google Ngrams  for "huge evolution"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=huge%20evolution&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chuge%20evolution%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Chuge%20evolution%3B%2Cc0) show a deceptively steep curve in the frequency of use 0 the absolute figures for use are, however, very small:

1. > **Emerging Perspectives on the Mobile Content Evolution - Page 74**

> *In the case of social media, however, a huge evolution could be expected.*

**an evolution** appears to mean "a huge example/process of evolution" and I think that is this meaning that "**evolution** carries in its "almost countable" sense. I would be inclined to accept this as correct.

2. > **Sustained Simulation Performance 2016: Proceedings of the ...** Michael M. Resch, ‎Wolfgang Bez, ‎Erich Focht · 2016 Page 12

> *Within the last decade, there was a huge evolution with regards to the HPC systems.*

Again -  as above

3. > **My Time My World - Page 142 Pratheek, ‎Pratheek Praveen Kumar · 2019 Page 142**

> *... the 21st century is just a minute phase in the huge evolution process that takes the world to higher levels of existence through restless and difficile passage.*

This uses "evolution" as an attributive noun, and is correct

4. > **The PAYTECH Book: The Payment Technology Handbook for ... Susanne Chishti, ‎Tony Craddock, ‎Robert Courtneidge · 2019**

> *By Andréa Toucinho Head of Studies, Prospective and Training, Partelya Consulting Instant payments represent a huge evolution for the payments market.*

As per 2.above.

5. > **Teacher Thinking: A Study of Practical Knowledge** Freema Elbaz · 2018

> *It started out being called a “Thinking Course”, and the evolution from “Thinking” to “Learning”, I think is a very interesting one, because in a sense it's a huge evolution of copping out.*

I think that this is simply wrong - I would accept "in copping out": the change (process of evolution) is taking place "with**in** (the context of) copping out.

6. > **How We Make Stuff Now: Turn Ideas into Products That Build ...** Jules Pieri · 2019 Page 21

> *“It's a huge evolution **in** the sophistication of wireless earbuds,” says Cannington.*

this is the correct form of 5.

Thus

> The huge evolution of new technologies.

is wrong, but

> The huge evolution **in** new technologies.

is correct

Answer (score -1):

No, the quote isn’t a predicate / assertion / truth statement, so it isn’t true. (For the same reason, isn’t false, either.)

Comment: Come on, you know that's not what the OP was trying to ask.